# Get JSON Nested Array Element in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, org.json

I'm using `org.json` to lookup json objects and values (`org.json` is a requirement), and I'm trying to reach the child array elements.

My json:

```
{
   "Info": {
     "name": "my_json",
},
   "my_array": {
     "arrays": [
       {
       "array 1": [
         {
           "name": "red",
           "server": "red1",
           "capacity": "123"
         },
        {
           "name": "blue",
           "server": "blue1",
           "capacity": "456"
        }
     ]
   },
   {
      "array 2": [
        {
          "name": "white",
          "server": "white1",
          "capacity": "1234"
        },
        {
          "name": "black",
          "server": "black1",
          "capacity": "4567"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

This outputs:

```
{"array 1":[
     {"name":"red","capacity":"123","server":"red1"},
     {"capacity":"456","name":"blue","name":"blue1"}
]}
{"array 2":[
     {"capacacity":"1234","name":"white","server":"white1"},
     {"name":"black","capacity":"4567","server":"black1"}
]}
{"array 1":[
     {"name":"red","capacity":"123","server":"red1"},
     {"capacity":"456","name":"blue","name":"blue1"}
]}
{"array 2":[
     {"capacity":"1234","name":"white","server":"white1"},
     {"name":"black","capacity":"4567","server":"black1"}
]}
```

The method looks like:

```
 public static String processJson(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String value = "";
    String jsonData = readFile(args[0]);
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    if (args[1].equals("my_array")) {
        JSONObject parent = jobj.getJSONObject("my_array");
        JSONArray jarr = parent.getJSONArray("arrays");
        for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject test1 = jarr.getJSONObject(j);
                System.out.println(test1);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I would like the return value to be:

```
[{"name":"red","capacity":"123","server":"red1"
{"capacity":"456","name":"blue","name":"blue1"}]
```

Is it possible to get `array 1` elements?
I thought the nested loop will take care of it, but it only outputs the same time.

Comment: What is args[1] ?

Comment: @jeanr I guess it is `my_array`

Comment: When I try to read the structure of your json payload it looks as this:my_array.arrays[0]."array 1"
my_array.arrays[1]."array 1"

Are you sure your json format is arranged neatly i.e. in a proper hierarchy or relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first element then you don't need a loop

```
       JSONObject test1 = jarr.getJSONObject(0);
       System.out.println(test1);
```

If you want to format `test1` your can

```
System.out.println (test1.toString ().replace ("{\"array 1\":", ""));
```

Comment: Nice! Removed both loops!

Comment: How would you remove `array 1` if it was passed as an argument? Foe example, `replace("{\"variable name\":", "")` doesn't remove the string.

Comment: You can use variables like `str.replace (var, "")`  where `var` is a String like `var = "{\"" + "array 1" + "\":";`